# Disabled radio button in simple_form with an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

What is the best way to place two radio button inside a simple_form, where 
one button is by default disabled and another is selected!

```
f.input_field :listing_type, as: :radio_buttons, collection: [ "lease", "sale"], :item_wrapper_class => 'inline'
```

this is giving me two buttons where both are enabled and selected. I want sale to be disabled and lease to be selected by default.

Comment: no, rails 3.2, but will it make any difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you have to make them separately with the same name so that one of them can be disabled.

```
<%= f.input :listing_type,     as: :radio_buttons, :disabled: true, input_html: { value: 'lease' } %>
<%= f.input :listing_type,     as: :radio_buttons, input_html: { value: 'sale' } %>
```

Comment: I have seen simple_form documentation and they does'nt seems to solve this problem. These frameworks are good when you are starting but at the same time you loose flexibility.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an updated answer. You can:

- Specify which radio button is disabled by adding hash to the collection: `collection: [['op1', 'val1', disabled: false], ['op2', 'val2', disabled: true]]`
- Specify which radio button is checked by either add checked to its collection hash, or add `checked: value_to_be_checked` to the main options hash.
  Here's an examples of both options:

example1:

```
<%= f.input_field :listing_type, as: :radio_buttons, collection: [ ['lease', 'lease', disabled: false], ['sale', 'sale', disabled: true]], checked: 'lease', :item_wrapper_class => 'inline' %>
```

example2:

```
<%= f.input_field :listing_type, as: :radio_buttons, collection: [ ['lease', 'lease', disabled: false, checked: true], ['sale', 'sale', disabled: true]], :item_wrapper_class => 'inline' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Radio Buttons behave the same as Select Options as far as I can tell.  If you pass an array to an `input`'s `collection` option consisting of the Display Text, the value of the input, and any additional HTML attributes - *in that order* - you can embed whatever you want in the radio buttons (or any inputs for that matter).

Ex:

```
radio_button_options = LeaseCalculator::TERMS.map do |term|
  ["#{term} Months",term, {disabled: (term > maximum_term_length)}]
end

= form.input :term,
    as: :radio,
    collection: radio_button_options
```

Here I put a conditional on the HTML5 disabled attribute.  It works perfectly in the resultant HTML.

```
<input id="lease_calculator_term_48" data-calculator-input="term" class="update_calculator" type="radio" value="48" name="lease_calculator[term]">
<input id="lease_calculator_term_60" data-calculator-input="term" class="update_calculator" disabled="disabled" type="radio" value="60" checked="checked" name="lease_calculator[term]">
```

NOTE: The second input has HTML5 Disabled on it, the first one does not.

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
f.input_field :listing_type, as: :radio_buttons, collection: [ "lease", "sale"], :item_wrapper_class => 'inline', :checked => "lease"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just hack radio_button disabled functionality with jquery **insist of separating out radio buttons.**

```
f.input_field :listing_type, as: :radio_buttons, collection: [ "lease", "sale"], :item_wrapper_class => 'inline', :checked=> "lease", :disabled=> true
```

**/app/assets/application.js**

```
$(':radio:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score -1):

See you can use the `form` helper to make your form and set the default value like this

```
 <% form_tag desired_path do %>
 <%= radio_button_tag(:options, "res_a", true) %>
 <%= label_tag "res a" %>
 <%= radio_button_tag(:options, "res_b") %>
 <%= label_tag "res_b" %>
 <%= submit_tag :value => "submit"%>
 <% end %>
```

by providing `true` you can make the option as default as shown.

Comment: I am asking for simple_form radio input with default selected, and disabled.